# Pass more than a value between non-terminal Bison rule

Tags: c, struct, parameter-passing, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to pass more than one value when i match a rule with my lexer (written in Flex).

```
{pattern_to_match}           {
                                 yylval.type_val.str=strdup(yytext);
                                 yylval.type_val.int=1;
                                 return TOKEN;
                             }
```

This is the lexer part

```
%union {
struct{
        char * str;
            int    int;
   }str_int;

%token <str_int> TOKEN

 TOKEN      {       
                printf("%s\n",$1.str_int.str);
                printf("%s\n",$1.str);
            }
```

and here we can see the Bison structure. I have written the two string into the printf as seen in a tutorial, but none works (both for the string and the int). What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `%union` directive looks ... well, "almost OK" in terms of what you've shown of it, but there's a missing close brace.  I cannot say anything about the part you omitted, but `int int` is a syntax error, so I have to assume that this is not what's there either.

The code in the braces (both the flex and bison sections) does not match the fragment shown in the union.

Here's some correct syntax (I added more names for discussion purposes, and some other items to make the output compile-able with `gcc -O -Wall -c`):

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
extern int yylex(void);
extern int yyerror(const char *);
%}

%union {
    struct named_for_discussion_below {
        char *pair_sval;
        int pair_ival;
    } pair;
    int single_ival;
}

%token <pair> TOKEN
%token <single_ival> INTEGER

%%

prog: exprlist;

exprlist: exprlist expr
        | /*empty*/
        ;

expr    : TOKEN { printf("got: %s %d\n", $1.pair_sval, $1.pair_ival); }
        | INTEGER { printf("got: %d\n", $1); }
        ;
```

Note that, because of the types supplied in the two `%token` directives, bison assumes that `$1` is an instance of `struct named_for_discussion_below`, containing `pair_sval` and `pair_ival`, when the token is `TOKEN`, but that `$1` is just a simple `single_ival` value when the token is `INTEGER`.  You must select the structure member (`.pair_sval` and `.pair_ival`) when accessing the `pair` value, but you must omit the word `pair`.  When accessing the `single_ival` you omit the word `single_ival` too; and since there's no `.field` sub-name, nothing else appears after `$1`.

---

#### Extended discussion

It may help, at least if you know the basics of how the generated parser works, to note here that each element of the parse stack is a `union` type.  (Well, it is after using `%union`, otherwise it's just an ordinary `int`.)

The `%union` directive supplies the contents for this type.  The internal name for this is `union YYSTYPE`, and it has a typedef-alias spelled `YYSTYPE`, which is what you (or flex) should use when setting up the auxiliary value for each token.  Each call to `yylex()` must return an ordinary `int` value, which is the token number (0 for EOF, 1 through 255 for an ordinary `char`, and token values starting at or above 256 for tokens).  (Byacc use `#define`s starting at 257, while modern bison uses an `enum` and starts at 258.)  Each call also sets `yylval` and the value in `yylval` is pushed (shifted) onto its parse stack, along with the token.  (Both bison and byacc use two parallel stacks, one for parser state and one for values, but that's an implementation detail you need not care about.  Other than "Bob Corbett wrote the first versions of both" I'm not sure why they both work the same way here.)

When bison (or byacc) emits code, it uses the assigned or assumed type, from `%token`, `%type`, or angle-bracket-supplied name, to add a union element name as needed.  For instance, suppose the yacc value stack is named `S` (it's not but just suppose), and suppose `$1` is actually `S[1]`, `$2` being `S[2]`, and so on.  Without a `%union` directive and no explicit types, `$n` just translates directly to `S[n]`.  When you introduce `%union`, though, it translates to `S[n].field`, where the `field` name comes from the implied or supplied type.

Thus, in the above, when handling an `INTEGER` which produces only a `single_ival`, bison/byacc generates what you need with no additional work on your part.  But, when handling a `TOKEN` that produces a `pair`, `S[1].pair` is not sufficient to select one element of the `struct`.  Adding `.pair_sval` selects the `char *` element of the `struct`.

The struct type's name, `struct named_for_discussion_below`, never appears in any automatically-generated code.  If you want to pass a copy of the struct type, or a pointer to an instance of it, to some routine—e.g., `alter(&$1)`, when `$1` expands to `S[1].pair`—*you* will need to use the struct type's name.  If you never do this, you can omit the name entirely.

Comment: I have done some copy/paste error and didn't notice them when I published it. By the way your answer made me realize what I was doing wrong! I'm a beginner in Bison and I feel like I'm still missing something. Thanks so much!!